# Can i use HTML tags in joomla template Language file?

Tags: joomla, ini

Can i use **(HTML) tag in template language file.**

DISCOUNT_COUPON_DESCRIPTION="Use GET10 coupon code and get 10% discount"

Comment: I recommend giving it a try to see if it works and if not then don't use it! This will be quicker than waiting for an answer here.

Comment: A language file is only for translations not html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's not advisable, but it is possible. You shouldn't though.